# Open Element on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologise in advance for the poor quality of this question but here goes:

I simply want an element to slide open on mouse click! That's it!

Specifically, i want a single menu item which, when clicked, will slide open to reveal a form.

What i'm after is almost exactly like an accordion menu in jQuery BUT they all rely on two or more elements to click on and open, whereas i only have one button whose default will be in 'closed' state.

I am a complete Javascript novice (even less than novice), so editing existing JS code can prove quite tricky and error prone to me, but it seems what i'm after is 'fairly' simple and everything i have found online is for multiple elements in a menu, so i thought i'd see if anyone could help.

I would have ideally asked this in the Javascript chat room but its empty at the mo.

I hope someone can help

Comment: Google for "javascript element toggle".

Comment: what do you mean "rely on two or more elements"? jQuery helps manipulate DOM elements or just one element :D

Comment: You see, i knew it would be obvious. Thanks Kevin, the trouble is i know so little JS that i don't know what to ask! Guess i deserved the mark down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hidden element (`slideUp()`ed or something), it won't be clickable, so you need an element inside it to always show so something can be clicked to allow the element to slide down. I've drawn up a quick example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/xZm9z/4/), using [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). If you want to slide the element down on click, then leave it there, replace `slideToggle()` with [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Please leave a comment if you don't understand anything.

Comment: OK, that looks EXACTLY what i'm after. I'll give it a try and hopefully mark this as answered. Thanks JW (and everyone who has answered) :)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I wish you the best on your journey to jQuery enlightenment :-)

Comment: I like that blue color (#76a7dc), if you don't mind I will steal it :)

Comment: @ogps92 Well, I 'stole' it from someone else, so feel free ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) the HTML Element using jQuery.

```
$("#id_of_elm").slideDown(duration_in _number);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/UN25J/

Comment: Hi Naveen, forgive my ignorance, but would i just link to the jquery library, then use your code for my element?

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to use the `slideDown()` jquery function. Add this code to the head of your HTML file (or, if this is going to be more than a small javascript project put the code in seperate `.js` file):

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#formId").hide();
    }
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
        $("#formId").slideDown();
    })
</script>
```

when `buttonId` is the id attribute of your button and `formId` is your form's id attribute.

Your going to also need to import the jquery script using the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

where `jquery.js` is the path to the jquery file you have.

**You can see a live demo (with the needed code) here:** http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/MkEMd/2/

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/fmQ4m/1/)

```
$('.box').hide(); // HIDE ALL .BOX

$('.click').click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Just Google for **jQuery** "*anything you need*"
 Ex: **jQuery slideToggle** and so on.

Comment: Thanks roXon, the trouble i had/have is that i didn't know what i needed to search for, if you know what i mean, hence my dumb question! JW has sorted it for me but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Dan... No problem! play with the demo! change/add code... discover the beauty of jQuery!